# publish reports--jenkins ci

Tags: html, xml

I have generated the test results in xml/html format using batch script.
Now I want to publish those reports on jenkins dash board.
Can anyone please help and tell me, how to publish reports on dashboard by providing external reports like (xml/html)?
Please let me know if any plugin exists for that.

Thanks in advance,
raj.

Answer (score 0):

You should use maven or ant build tool, not batch.

For maven job type, it will be done automatically.